# What is wrong with these static getter & setter methods - Android?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, getter-setter

I'm befuddled by a very tiny problem in my Android code. All the getters and setters I created in a custom class (i.e. 'ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT') give me the following 'Java NullPointerException':

```
05-31 13:37:13.222  29262-29262/com.whitsoft.stan E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.whitsoft.stan.mods.ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT.setSingleRoomsNumberTextValue(ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT.java:61)
        at com.whitsoft.stan.utils.DataFixer.updateRelevantViewsWithSelectedData(DataFixer.java:48)
        at com.whitsoft.stan.mods.StanListFragment.checkIfTheListAdapterDataHasChanged(StanListFragment.java:98)
        at com.whitsoft.stan.mods.StanListFragment.onActivityCreated(StanListFragment.java:49)
        at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1707)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:921)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the custom class ('ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT') where the getters & setters are implemented:

```
public class ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT extends RelativeLayout {

LayoutInflater stanInflater;
private static TextView singleRoomsNumberTV, singleRoomsDescTV, vipRoomsNumberTV, vipRoomsDescTV;

public ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT(Context context) {
    super(context);

    stanInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    initializeAndLayoutChildren();
}

public ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    stanInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    initializeAndLayoutChildren();
}

public ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    stanInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    initializeAndLayoutChildren();
}

private void initializeAndLayoutChildren() {

    stanInflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_rlyt_results_room_info, this, true);

    singleRoomsNumberTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stan_Single_Rooms_Number_TV);
    singleRoomsDescTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stan_Single_Rooms_Description_TV);
    vipRoomsNumberTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stan_VIP_Rooms_Number_TV);
    vipRoomsDescTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stan_VIP_Rooms_Description_TV);
}

public static String getSingleRoomsNumberTextValue() {
    return singleRoomsNumberTV.getText().toString();
}

public static void setSingleRoomsNumberTextValue(String singleRoomsNumberText) {
    singleRoomsNumberTV.setText(singleRoomsNumberText);
} 

public static void setVipRoomsNumberTextValue (String vipRoomsNumberText) {
    vipRoomsNumberTV.setText(vipRoomsNumberText);
}

public static String getVipRoomsDescTextValue () {
    return vipRoomsDescTV.getText().toString();
}

public static void setVipRoomsDescTextValue (String vipRoomsDescText) {
    vipRoomsDescTV.setText(vipRoomsDescText);
}  }
```

...as you can see I love using static getters and setters as it gives me easy access to the required views with a single line of code. The really odd thing about this error I am getting at runtime is that I have two other classes like this one that use exactly the same setup - and those classes work fine (update the data as required). However, when this class's setters are called with the following calls they all fail to execute:

```
ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT.setSingleRoomsNumberTextValue(singleRoomsNumberInfo);
    ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT.setSingleRoomsDescTextValue(singleRoomsDescInfo);
    ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT.setVipRoomsNumberTextValue(vipRoomsNumberInfo);
    ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT.setVipRoomsDescTextValue(vipRoomsDescInfo);
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.
Shore-T.

Comment: Have you run initializeAndLayoutChildren() function before calling setter?

Comment: And are you sure that your `findViewById` calls return the correct view reference and not `null` (which happens if the passed *id* couldn't be found). And to make it quick: static getters and setters for instance variables are very bad code.

Comment: Wow, thanks Tom - you nailed the problem right on the head. I actually have two layout .xml files for this custom class (one for the portrait view and one for the layout view). In my haste I didn't check to see if the TextView IDs were the same in both the portrait and landscape layout files. Thus, the `findViewById()` methods actually only link the portrait layout file views (TextViews) into Java at runtime and not the landscape views as they have different IDs. This what causes the error when the device is in the landscape orientation. Stupid mistake on my part - I feel like slapping myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem is that you are trying to set the texts of some `null` text views. For example, the following line:

```
ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT.setSingleRoomsNumberTextValue(singleRoomsNumberInfo);
```

tries to do the following:

```
singleRoomsNumberTV.setText(singleRoomsNumberText);
```

But what is singleRoomsNumberTV? Where is it assigned? You need to call:

```
new ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT(this);
```

from your activity to initialize the static TextViews.

Comment: Matei, you and Tom were both correct. However, you were the only one that provided an answer that I could select as the correct answer here on SO...and so you get the 'green tick'. Thanks to everyone that tried to assist me though - that includes Eran especially.

Answer (score 1):

Your static getters and setters access static references that get initialized by a non-static method - `initializeAndLayoutChildren`. When you initialize a static variable in a non-static method, you run the risk of accessing the static variable before it is initialized. You also run the risk of initializing the static variables multiple times - each time a new instance is created.

For example, the static method `setSingleRoomsNumberTextValue` accesses the static variable `singleRoomsNumberTV` which gets initialized by the instance method `initializeAndLayoutChildren` called by the constructor of `ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT`. If you call that static method before creating any instance of `ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT`, you'll get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: That sounds logical Eran, but in this case the 'initializeAndLayoutChildren' non-static method is called everytime you call the class constructor (which happens everytime you even make a reference to the class name - as is the case when you run this code:  `ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT.setSingleRoomsNumberTextValue(singleRoomsNumberInfo);`  ...so there is actually no risk of not initializing the relevant views before calling the static getter and setter methods. Thus this is not the correct answer in this case - please see comments on initial post. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: *"which happens everytime you even make a reference to the class name - as is the case when you run this code: `ResultsRoomInfoCustRLYT.setSingleRoomsNumberTextValue(singleRoomsNumberInfo);` ...so there is actually no risk of not initializing the relevant views before calling the static getter and setter methods"* So you think, if you call a static method like the one you've mentioned the constructor will be called, as well? This is wrong. And since it is wrong, your assumption, that there is no risk, is wrong as well.

Comment: @Shore-T No, referring to a class name doesn't invoke the constructor of that class, creating an instance of the class does (which is exactly what the answer you accepted told you to do). I didn't make such a suggestion, since it seems like bad design to initialize static variables from a non static method.

Comment: Thanks guys...points taken. Code works now. Thanks for your help.